# matplotlib buttons not displaying on the same window

Tags: python, matplotlib, pycharm

I've made a simple GUI game with matplotlib, I can get it running well on PyCharm if I check "Run with Python Console" in config options.

The problem comes when I try to run it from terminal by doing

`python MyGame.py`

Indeed, when doing this, the matplotlib window only displays the plots, but not the widget buttons, and the latters only appear in a second window, when I close the first one...

Is there a way to get all the plots and the buttons in the same window, as it does in PyCharm with my config?

Here is an example of code  having the unexpected behaviour

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.widgets as widgets

ax = plt.subplot()
ax.plot(.5,.6, marker='o', markersize=15, color='k')

plt.show()

buttonShape = plt.axes([.4, .2, .2, .1])
button = widgets.Button(buttonShape, "I am a button")

plt.show()
```

Thanks,

Vic

Comment: You report about a problem you observe by running some code that nobody except you has knowledge about.

Comment: @Vic3198 please provide more details. What does your code look like, especially the one that generates the widgets etc.? What are the package dependencies? How are you running it? Is PyCharm adding some packages / command line arguments that you're not including when you're running your Python script in the terminal?

Comment: Ok sorry, just added the code in my post. In the meantime, I found that the problem is that I use plt.show() twice. But is there a way to do so and have the the circle and the button displayed in the same window? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You got two plt.show() in your code.
The first one shows the figure you have constructed so far. Then you close it with the mouse. And then you start constructing a new one.
Just remove the first plt.show()